# Bug in VS 2022 (Enable XAML Designer not working)

Tags: wpf, xaml, xaml-designer

I recently started to use Visual Studio 2022 Professional edition. Whenever I enable visual designer from :

`Tools -> Options -> XAML Designer -> General`

I check to enable the XAML designer:

[image]

When I restart the Visual Studio IDE, **nothing is changed**, and the option is unchecked again. I tried multiple times, and unfortunately, the XAML code is only visible while the XAML designer is always unchecked.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. You need to find the exact conditions to reproduce this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I was having a similar issue.

Make sure you're opening the project via the actual C# project file and not through the folder explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you developing a WinUI 3.0 App?

If so, you are out of luck.
An XAML Designer for that **does not exist** yet. And probably won't exist in the near future.
[See this issue on Github](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/5917) to get the details.